# how to merge consecutive empty cells in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel file with something like below data
[Original data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgGGY.png)

[image]
I want to merge all empty cells (automatically) which appears before it, like below
[after merging should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zd5uu.png)
[image]

As there are many files, can't do it manually so looking for way to do using script or something else.
Thought of doing using autoit but couldn't.
Please help :)

have not done vba code anytime but could reach till below the help of google

```
Sub abc()
Dim a As Integer
Dim b As Integer
Dim c As Integer
b=1
For a = b To 308
If Cells(a, c) = "" Then
Range(Cells(a, c), Cells(a - 1, c)).Merge
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code for me site.  Please show your code attempts in the original post using [edit]

Comment: @ScottCraner edited .. please check and help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i was in same situation once after some googling i was able to do, I dont have my script right now, but your code looks easy and with below changes you can achieve what you are looking for.
give it a try.

I assume
C is column counts for which you need to do this merging
and  308 is row count you have..

`Sub abc()
    Dim a As Integer
    Dim b As Integer
    Dim c As Integer
    For c = 1 To 4
    b = 3
    For a = b - 1 To 308
    If Cells(a, c) = "" Then
    Range(Cells(a, c), Cells(a - 1, c)).Merge
    Else
    b = a
    End If
    Next
    Next
    End Sub`

Comment: that was quick! thanks for the prompt response, let me try. :)

Comment: Aweosme! it worked! i got where i  was going wrong, I didn't initialize C, and else  condition which was key point here.

Comment: glad could help.. enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub mergeBlankRows()
    Dim a As Integer
    Dim b As Integer
    Dim c As Integer
    Dim nRow As Integer
    Dim nCol As Integer
    nRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    nCol = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
    For c = 1 To nCol
    b = 3
    For a = b - 1 To nRow
    If Cells(a, c) = "" Then
    Range(Cells(a, c), Cells(a - 1, c)).Merge
    Range(Cells(a, c), Cells(a - 1, c)).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    Range(Cells(a, c), Cells(a - 1, c)).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    Else
    b = a
    End If
    Next
    Next
End Sub
```

`nRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count` and `nCol = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count` will get the number of used columns and rows in the active worksheet.